# Последовательность Коллатца. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не получается выполнить второй этап этой задачи, в обучающих материалах использовались только эти функции и инструкции + инструкция return. Можно использовать циклы for, while:

[image: Задача]

```
#Первый этап задачи (выполнил)
def collatz():
    numberX = int(input())
    if numberX % 2 == 0:
        print(numberX // 2)
    else:
        print(3 * numberX + 1)

#Второй этап задачи (не выполнил, выдаёт ошибку.)
number = collatz()
if int(number) % 2 == 0:
    print(int(collatz()) // 2)
else:
    print(3 * int(collatz()) + 1)
```

Comment: `collatz()` dolzno chtoto vozwrashchat, dobavte `return` w `collatz()`

Comment: @entithat клавиатура сломалось?

Comment: @Danis, I haven't installed rus lang yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как сказал [@entithat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272305/entithat) функция `collatz` должна что то возвращать, поэтому `print` замените на `return`

```
def collatz():
    numberX = int(input())
    if numberX % 2 == 0:
        return numberX // 2
    else:
        return 3 * numberX + 1
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vr94svJR @Danis Почему то два раза запрашивает ввести значение, а потом выдаёт ответ. Что-то работает не правильно. Как вы думаете, как сделать так, что бы программа предлагала ввести число, а затем последовательно вызывала функцию collatz() для этого числа и значений, возвращаемых очередным вызовом этой функции, пока на каком то этапе не будет возвращено значение 1?

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, функция должна что-то возвращать, если идёт речь об одном этапе. А если хотите довести число до единицы, добавьте цикл `while`.

```
def collatz_operation(n):
    return n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else 3 * n + 1

def collatz():
    number = int(input())
    while number > 1:
        print(number)
        number = collatz_operation(number)
    print(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz(n):

    while n != 1:

        print(n)

        if n % 2 == 1:

            n= 3 * n + 1

        else:

            n = n // 2

        print(n)

n= int(input("Введи число:"))

collatz(n)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]